# Is there any algorithm for random number generation whose pattern cannot be revealed?

Tags: algorithm, random

Can it be possible to create random number whose pattern of getting the next random number never be repeated even the universe ends.

Comment: Are you constraining this in any way, for example, that it must be a type that can be represented in n bits?

Comment: Honestly, this question is very unclear.

Comment: No the random number can be any number available in the universe. The only thing I am curious the pattern that we will use might repeat on some time

Comment: So a pattern that followed steps to increment a number by each of the the decimal digits of PI would suffice? It also makes it a number theory issue, and possibly better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I read this security rule-of-thumb:

> All processes which require non-trivial random numbers MUST attempt to
>   use openssl_pseudo_random_bytes(). You MAY fallback to
>   mcrypt_create_iv() with the source set to MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM. You MAY
>   also attempt to directly read bytes from /dev/urandom. If all else
>   fails, and you have no other choice, you MUST instead generate a value
>   by strongly mixing multiple sources of available random or secret
>   values.

http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  bignum getUniqueRandom()
  {
         static bignum sum = 0;
         sum += rand();
         return sum;
  }
```

That way the next random number will be always greater than the previous (by a random factor between 0 and 1) and as result the numbers returned will never repeat.

edit:
The actual approach when randomness requirements are so high is to use a hardware random number generator; there are for example chips that measure atom decays of background radiation generating truly random seeds. Of course the nature or *randomness* is such that there is never a guarantee a pattern *can't* repeat, or you'd be damaging the actual randomness of the result. But the pattern can't be repeated by any technical/mathematical means, so the repeats are meaningless.

Comment: Not very random if they're always increasing

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Why, but unique! :D For all practical purposes you normally use a sufficiently large random number, making the probability of collision low enough. For completely guaranteed uniqueness though you need an autoincrement key of infinite size; by combining the two approaches you're getting a guaranteed unique key with *some* randomness. You need to decide how much randomness you need to be *actually* secure and how big the "infinite" autoincrement must be to satisfy demands of some manager/customer who doesn't understand probability and isn't satisfied with 10e-300 chance.

Comment: If the purpose is to be used in, say, cryptography, then using an algorithm with a defined order, and forcing the steps to always be unidirectional would limit it, by my definition of randomness. A better approach to avoid collisions would be to track what results have been issued, and make a decision *then*.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: That 1) requires a constantly growing database of past values which needs to be searched for repeats, increasing difficulty in an unpractical way, 2) requires a constantly growing number of random bits generated as the randomness pool is diminished by past results. It's really no better in the long run. The only real solution is to get a *good* randomness source and generate *enough* of it, never striving for absolute perfection and flat zero probability.

Comment: (after all, an algorithm to create enough unique numbers to give every planck time of every second of existence of every atom in the universe a unique identifier isn't all that difficult; it will just still have infinitisemally small chance of creating a collision. The flat zero is a fool's errand.)

Answer (score 0):

In Layman's terms,  **no**; In order to generate a particular data form, such as a string or integer, you must have an algorithm of some sort, which obviously cannot be 100% untraceable...

Basically, the final product myust come from a series of events (algorithm) in which is impossible to keep 'unrevealed'.

Answer (score 0):

At every step in the execution of a computer program, the total internal state determines what the next total internal state will be. This internal state must be represented by some number of bits--all of the memory used by the program, registers of the processor, anything else that affects it. There can only be 2**N possible states given N bits of state information.

Since any given state T will lead to the same state T+1 (that's what "deterministic" means), the algorithm *must* eventually repeat itself after no more than 2**N steps. So what limits the cycle length of an RNG is the number of bits of internal state. A simple LCG might have only 32 bits of state, and therefore a cycle <= 2^32. Something like Mersenne Twister has 19968 bits of internal state, and its period is 2^19937-1.

So for any deterministic algorithm to be "unrepeatable in the history of the Universe", you'll probably need most of the atoms of the Universe to be memory for its internal state.